# Android - Button not firing

Tags: android

Need help trying to figure out why the button onCLick event isn't working. I set it in onCreate but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Setup Refresh button listener.
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
        btn.setOnClickListener(btnRefreshClick);    
    }

    private OnClickListener btnRefreshClick = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Data from Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

I even took out the Toast call and tried to write to LogCat but when I put a breakpoint on the Log.e statement, it never gets there.

Comment: Try to remove `implements OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is valid and works.
You just should remove `implements OnClickListener` if you don't override the method `onClick` directly in your activity.

Add your .xml to your question because the problem looks to be here

Comment: Thanks, after removing the OnClickListener I still had the issue but I found out why....I was using setContext to a different layout before setting the OnClickListener event.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're pressing the right button? Are you sure you're resource id/layout is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying an `OnClickListener` inside your `onCreate()` method... this isn't right.  If your activity is implementing OnClickListener, there should be a derived onClick() method.

Use:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

instead and pop up the toast from the onClick() method separate from your onCreate().

Otherwise, you can try this instead:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Data from Server",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Technically, yours should work though, so make sure you're clicking the right button and that you don't have `onClick` in your layout xml for the button.